# ¿Por qué no se refleja el datatable en mi tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, datatables, bootstrap-4

Desconozco el por qué no puede aplicarse el datatable a la tabla que tengo cuando sigo los pasos para añadirlo, he intentado con realizar nuevamente todo desde el inicio pero aún así sigue sin reflejarse

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Este lo obtuve de datatable -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.css"/>
        
<!-- La tabla -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <?php
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                            <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </table>
            </div>
            
            
<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- El otro script que obtuve de datatable y el código que llama a la función  -->            

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            } );
        </script>
```

¿Es el navegador? ¿Es la versión de Bootstrap? ¿Estoy olvidando cerrar alguna etiqueta? Porque sigo las indicaciones de datatables.net seleccionando la versión de bootstrap 4 y jquery 3 para evitar tantos problemas, pero continúa siendo de esa manera

Comment: El contenido que tienes en el for en php que genera los tr debe de ir dentro de una etiqueta <tbody>

Comment: Cierto... supongo que seguir esa "guía" al pie de la letra me hizo incapaz de ver ese apartado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Datatables** utiliza un sistema un poco distinto para usar atributos `colspan` o `rowspan`. En este [enlace a su documentación](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) encontrarás más información.

En tu caso concreto no deberias usar ninguno, puesto que tus columnas son **3** y sin embargo defines **3** encabezados `th` pero uno con `colspan="2"`, como si luego hubiera 4 columnas, que no las hay, y eso provoca error en el javascript de *datatables*.

En este snippet mostrado a continuación tan solo le he quitado el colspan y funciona bien (exceptuando el código php que se pone por enmedio porque no está resuelto, pero ya no da error de javascript).

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Este lo obtuve de datatable -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.css"/>
        
<!-- La tabla -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <?php
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                            <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </table>
            </div>
            
            
<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- El otro script que obtuve de datatable y el código que llama a la función  -->            

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            } );
        </script>
```

**Datatables** necesita que cada columna tenga su propio encabezado, sin excepción, pero permite usar dos encabezados, donde se puede usar el primero con `colspan` y `rowspan` y el segundo debe corresponderse con las columnas de forma exacta.

Por ejemplo, tu código podria ser válido tambien de este modo:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Este lo obtuve de datatable -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.css"/>
        
<!-- La tabla -->
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="process.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  </table>
</div>
            
            
<!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- El otro script que obtuve de datatable y el código que llama a la función  -->            

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            } );
        </script>
```

Fíjate que he separado los botones en dos columnas, para que coincidieran con los segundos encabezados.

Comment: Luego de leer la documentación puedo "verlo", pero realmente necesitaba ayuda, muchas gracias por haberla otorgado

Comment: Tambien puedes verlo en mi respuesta, tan solo dale al enlace "Mostrar fragmento de codigo" y una vez expandido le das al botón Ejecutar que aparece al pie de cada fragmento para ejecutarlo.   Los pongo así para que la respuesta no sea larga de leer y se entienda con la explicación, pero los fragmentos son para ejecutarse y pueden "verse" aqui tambien :-)

Comment: Nuevamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Me alegro te haya servido :-) Saludos!